# Simple form placeholders in combination with ckEditor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ckeditor, simple-form

I'm creating an admin system in Ruby on Rails 3.1, and I've got a problem. Normally I would use the simple_form locale file to add a placeholder to any given field. Except I can't get it to work within a ckEditor text_area. The placeholder I provided simply does not show up.

Locale file:

```
admin:
  excerpt: "placeholder text"
  body: "placeholder text"
```

show.html.haml >>

```
= simple_form_for [ :admin, @news_item ] do |f|
  = f.input :title
  = f.input :excerpt do 
    .ckEditor= f.text_area :excerpt
  = f.input :body do
    .ckEditor= f.text_area :body
  = f.submit
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this link for a fully featured Ckeditor integration gem for rails.
 https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/